# Update electron app via npm update

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have an app published in a local npm repo and this app is a main dependency of my second electron app. I've built electron app based on `node_modules/my-first-app/dist/index.html`. Is there any way to set up auto-updater so that it calls `npm update my-first-app` and re-build itself depending on gotten version? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Electron build app can be updated via electron-simple-updater (npm package) and you need to write few lines of code to update your project.

Comment: Your answer is unhelpful because you told the OP to "write some lines of code" instead of demonstrating where, how and what to write. See [Writing a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)